# A metalun made of LUNs on two RAID groups

Tags: raid, storage, storage-area-network

Does it make sense to have a metalun made of LUNs on two RAID groups, where 1 RG contains 5 disks and the other 9?

Can the CX 700 use this config efficiently? Both RAID5.

I guess not, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

As long as its the concatenated type and you don't care about the performance difference, it'll work fine.

Comment: what if it's striped metalun having disks with equal capacity?

Comment: I don't agree with cagenut , concatenated type will have  impact on performance..Striped metalun can give performance boost ..however, the its not an optimal configuration,at least ,thats what i believe. But i would like to know if i still can go with the abvove config... plz advise...thanks

Comment: why there's no comment ??

Admins(@ chopper ) need your advise

Comment: @wildchild if you don't agree with this answer, why did you accept it?

Comment: I am sorry, that was by mistake..can somebody explain ..i am still waiting for the answer...
thanks

Comment: Not sure what else there is to add here.  I recommended concatenated, you are correct if you make them the same size you can go with striped.  Since you obviously understand the difference between the two, and since you told us nothing about the application using the LUN, what else is there to say?